# How to debug single Karma test using WebStorm

Tags: karma-runner, webstorm, karma-coverage

I am trying to debug single test using Karma and WebStorm.
I found that this can be done,

1. when I do not use coverage reporter and run karma.config with  [--
   reporter progress](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/karma-users/OocaR-ZgHO8/D3RYnQ3Aeq4J), but this is not working
2. changing `it into fit` in unit test.

How to debug single Karma test using WebStorm?

karma.config

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js')({env: 'test'});

  var configuration = {

    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'tests/reports/units.html',
      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: 'A sample project description',
      groupSuites: true,
      useCompactStyle: true,
      useLegacyStyle: true
    },




    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    /*
     * Frameworks to use
     *
     * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     */
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [ ],

    /*
     * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
     *
     * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.js
     */
    files: [ { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.js', watched: false } ],

    /*
     * preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
     * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
     */
    preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

    // Webpack Config at ./webpack.test.js
    webpack: testWebpackConfig,

   // coverageReporter: {
   //   type: 'in-memory'
   // },

    remapCoverageReporter: {
      'text-summary': null,
      json: './coverage/coverage.json',
      html: './coverage/html'
    },

    // Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    webpackMiddleware: { stats: 'errors-only'},

    /*
     * test results reporter to use
     *
     * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
     * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
     */

    // CHANGE !!!
    reporters: [ 'progress' ],

    //reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage', 'remap-coverage', 'progress', 'html'  ],
    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    /*
     * level of logging
     * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
     */
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    /*
     * start these browsers
     * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     */
    browsers: [
      'Chrome'
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeTravisCi: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    /*
     * Continuous Integration mode
     * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
     */
    singleRun: process.env.TRAVIS ? true : false
  };

  if (process.env.TRAVIS){
    configuration.browsers = ['PhantomJS'];
  }

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Focused' specs/suits work for me (WebStorm 2016.3 EAP) - only `fdescribe`/`fit` suits/tests results are shown in Test runner console.

If you miss a possibility to run individual karma tests/suits, please follow [WEB-13173](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173) for updates. See also https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1235